# regex search works with cypher parser 1.9 not with version 2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I followed http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/ for search using regular expression, it looks like Cypher2 has a problem with the operator "=~" it works for cypher parser 1.9 but not with version 2

**==> http://console.neo4j.org/**

```
Query:
CYPHER 1.9  START n=node(*) 
WHERE n.name =~ 'T.*' 
RETURN n

result=OK
```

Doesn't work after switching to cypher parser 2:

```
Query:
START n=node(*) 
WHERE n.name =~ 'T.*' 
RETURN n
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v1_9.commands.Query cannot be cast to org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.commands.AbstractQuery
```

**==> Neo4j 2.0.0-M06**

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE n.name =~ 's.*' 
RETURN n  

Expected 2 to be a java.lang.String, but it was a java.lang.Integer
STATEMENT_EXECUTION_ERROR
```

Any hint?

Comment: Are you having that problem on your own Neo4j instance or just at console.neo4j.org? I've seen a possibly related issue at the online console, but as fair as I can tell it is a problem in that web application, not in Neo4j. Also, your second query works for me on a fresh console, but not if I run your first query and then your second. Again, I think it's in the web app, not in Neo4j.

Comment: The second error output is from my own Neo4j server instance locally installed. the same query works at  console.neo4j.org ONLY with cupher 1.9 not with 2.

Comment: Recent builds of Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1 this should work, and console works now as Peter says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is now updated and working with the regexp for Neo4j 2.0 again, see http://console.neo4j.org/r/dcizjv

```
START n=node(*) 
WHERE n.name =~ 'T.*' 
RETURN n
```